# Make chrome display only page (No tabs or url bar)

Tags: google-chrome, browsing

Is there a way to display a webpage without any bars (taskbar, url bar etc)?

Comment: If you press `F11` the page will be displayed full-screen with no additional information.

Comment: I really would like this because tabs are the biggest productivity suck ever.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to display a webpage without any bars (task bar, url bar etc)?

You can use use either full screen mode or kiosk mode.

---

#### Full screen mode

If Chrome is already running:

- Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle full screen mode.

To start Chrome in full screen mode:

- From a `cmd` shell, batch file or shortcut run the following command:

  ```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen www.google.com
  ```
- Replace `www.google.com` as appropriate.
- Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to exit full screen mode.

---

#### Kiosk mode

- From a `cmd` shell, batch file, or shortcut run the following command:

  ```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk www.google.com
  ```
- Replace `www.google.com` as appropriate.
- Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to exit chrome.
- Pressing <kbd>f11</kbd> has no effect in Kiosk mode.

Comment: But full screen mode still displays tabs and address bar!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1736653/28765 below for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable this setting `View > Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen`

[image]

Comment: This is the crucial piece of information! Not sure why it hasn't been upvoted (except by me...)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to enter full screen mode.  This will not start the window in full screen however; you will need to press <kbd>F11</kbd> after you have opened the webpage.

Comment: But this mode still displays tabs and address bar!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1736653/28765 above for the answer.